# restriction of smooth function

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $C=\{ (x,y)  \in \mathbb{R^2}| x+y^3=1\}$ proof restriction  of any smooth function $f:\mathbb{R^2} \to \mathbb{R}$ on $C$ is is smooth function. ($f|_{C}$ is smooth) .

I think we must show $C$ is
smooth  submanifold of $\mathbb{R^2}$ . Is this true?

Comment: Yeah. It suffices to show $C$ is an immersed or embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ because then the inclusion map is smooth. For that it suffices to show $F$ is a smooth submersion on $C$.